# My Vue app won't mount because of an error: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': ')' is not a valid attribute name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom

this is my `main.js`:

```
 window.GCartVue = new Vue({
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
  el: "#checkout",
});
```

My `index.html` where the app mounts is `<div id="checkout"></div>`

The window.GCartVue is just so I can access the app throughout our WordPress site. This code has been working, but I started to refactor our vuex and I'm wondering if there is an uncaught error somewhere in there and it is causing this issue. The JS error log wasn't so helpful. Any insight is welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Buried deep in one of my components several layers deep, there was a rogue ")" and that is exactly what the issue was. Thanks!